# How can I get "is not" to be highlighted as a pythonOperator?

Tags: python, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to modify the python.vim syntax file so that "is not" is highlighted as single pythonOperator.

For example, this is what happen now:

[image: this is what happen now]

I've tried changing python.vim in several ways. For example:

```
--- python.vim.orig 2013-08-19 10:21:54.379892386 -0700                                                                                                   
+++ python.vim  2013-08-19 10:21:58.979892308 -0700
@@ -152,6 +152,7 @@ 
 syn keyword pythonPreCondit     import from
 syn keyword pythonException     try except finally
 syn keyword pythonOperator      and in is not or 
+syn match   pythonOperator      "is not"

 if s:Python2Syntax()
 if !s:Enabled("g:python_print_as_function")
```

But nothing seems to work.

What's interesting is that if I remove "is" and "not" and all the other python.vim syntax files, as in:

```
--- python.vim.orig 2013-08-19 10:21:54.379892386 -0700                                                                                                   
+++ python.vim  2013-08-19 10:41:37.067873208 -0700
@@ -151,7 +151,7 @@ 
 syn keyword pythonConditional   if elif else
 syn keyword pythonPreCondit     import from
 syn keyword pythonException     try except finally
-syn keyword pythonOperator      and in is not or 
+syn keyword pythonOperator      and in or 

 if s:Python2Syntax()
   if !s:Enabled("g:python_print_as_function")
```

The "is" is still highlighted. Weird.

Comment: What's the difference between is being highlighted as "one operator" and the tokens `is` and `not` being individually and independently highlighted as keywords/operators?

Comment: well the real problem is that "not" is not being highlighted.

Comment: With the unchanged `python.vim` it should be highlighted, shouldn't it?

Comment: correct. I found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nevermind, turns out [vim-cute-python](https://github.com/ehamberg/vim-cute-python/blob/master/after/syntax/python.vim#L7) has the line:

```
syntax clear pythonOperator
```

That was discarding all my changes to pythonOperator.